# vc-waypoints.min.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: t is not a function

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have been trying to figure out what kind of error is this one? Somehow I cannot find what it is and where does it come from?

[following code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dq8ap.png)

I'm using wordpress, wp-bakery builder if that helps.

Thanks in advance, appreciate all suggestions or advice.

Tried to find the source of code, but since I'm a beginner..I have no clue where to look for it.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557